# How to map JSON objects with different names to TS model?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, mapping

I'm using the recent version of Angular (7.x.x).
I have a JSON API given looking like:

```
{
  "objectA": {
  "a": {
    "aa": "hello",
    "ab": "xyz"
   },
"b": null,
"c": {
  "ca": null,
  "cb": null,
  "cc": null,
  "cd": "hi",
  "ce": null,
  "cf": null
    }
 },

  "objectB": {
  "a": {
    "aa": "hey",
    "ab": "abc"
   },
  "b": null,
  "c": {
    "ca": null,
    "cb": null,
    "cc": null,
    "cd": null,
    "ce": null,
    "cf": null
  }
}, ...}
```

All my objects have the same structure. Now I want to map them into a typescript object.

My model looks like:

```
 export interface MyObject {
 name: string;
 a: A;
 b?: any;
 c: C;}

 export interface C{
 ca?: any;
 cb?: any;
 cc?: any;
 cd?: any;
 ce?: any;
 cf?: any;}

 export interface A {
 aa: string;
 ab: string;
 ac?: string;}
```

How can I get the name of the object like "objectA" into the variable "name" of the interface "Object". As a result I want to return a array of objects.

My service:

```
 getResults(): Observable<MyObject[]> {
return this.http.get<MyObject[]>(this.url, {
  headers: this.headers
 })
```

My component:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.getObjects();}

getObjects(): void {
this.service.getResults()
  .subscribe(data=> {
    this.objects= data;
  });}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use `startsWith('object')` to identify every different 'entry'

Comment: please give desired result example

Comment: Is the JSON response an array?, as how could you create a model for such a repeating object?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
getResults(): Observable<MyObject[]> {
    return this.http.get<ApiResponse>[]>(this.url, {
        headers: this.headers
    }).pipe(map((response: ApiResponse) => {
        const myObjs: MyObject[] = [];
        Object.keys(response).forEach((key) => {
            // Now you have the "name" value
            myObjs.push({
                ...response[key],
                name: key
            };
        });
        return myObjs;
    }));
}
```

Object.keys() is the key to getting the value that you want to put into the name.  I didn't test this in a running environment, but it'll get you darn close to your solution.  You'll need an interface to represent the API's response.  That's what you're really asking for from the http.get.  Then you're mapping it to a response of MyObject[].